# jQuery multiple selectors order

Tags: jquery, selector, coalesce

I would like to select multiple buttons and click the first in order. Something like `COALESCE` function.

I tried this:

```
$(".selector1, .selector2, .selector3").first().click();
```

This works but the selection follows the DOM order and not my selector query order. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery always returns elements in DOM order, so you'll need to do something along these lines:

```
$.each(['.selector1', '.selector2', '.selector3'], function(i, selector) {
    var res = $(selector);
    if (res.length) {
        res.first().click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

You could poor that into a jQuery extension like so:

```
$.coalesce = function(selectors) {
    var match;
    var selector = $.each(selectors, function(i, selector) {
        var res = $(selector);
        if (res.length) {
            match = res;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return match || $([]);
};
```

And then call

> $.coalesce(['.selector1', '.selector2',
>   '.selector3']).first().click();

Comment: And what do you think about this:    ($(".selector1")[0]||$(".selector2")[0]).click();

Not so beautiful, but it works...

Comment: That would work, but it would get ugly when adding a few selectors very soon. You could create a jQuery extension for the above and call it like $.coalesce(['.selector1', '.selector2']).first().click();

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the elements with each() will give the right order, like so:

```
var elms = [".selector1", ".selector2", ".selector3"];

$.each(elms, function(index, item) {
    $(item).append('<br><br>This is item '+index);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fe9KH/1/)

Comment: Do you mean that the simple selector has DOM order and the same selector with each has another order?!?!

Comment: You are of course right! Initially wrote it the same way Gerry did, but changed it last minute when I noticed another answer that was pretty much the same as mine, did'nt notice the results also changed. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to get arrays of elements, then concatenate them, like this:

```
$($(".selector1").get().concat($(".selector2").get(), $(".selector3").get())).first().click();
```